# Interesting integral formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I looked around and found that integrals of the form

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-1}}{a+x^n}, a,m,n \in \mathbb{R}, 0<m<n, 0<a$$

seem to occur very often:

Just to give a few examples (the formula given below would solve them all right away):

[How can I compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1+t^4}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43457/how-can-i-solve-the-integral-int-0-infty-fracdt1t4)

[Simpler way to compute a definite integral without resorting to partial fractions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fractions)

[Is this definite integral really independent of a parameter? How can it be shown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/is-this-definite-integral-really-independent-of-a-parameter-how-can-it-be-shown/16987#16987)

[Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + 2x + 2} \mathrm{d} x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34189/integrating-int-0-infty-frac1x2-2x-2dx)

Even more surprising was that there seems to be a (quite beautiful) closed form, namely:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-1}}{a+x^n}=\frac{\pi}{n}  \left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^{1-\frac{m}{n}} \csc \left(m \cdot \frac{\pi 
   }{n}\right)$$

(This result is from Mathematica). I tried to derive this result by integrating (brute force) but you get hypergeometric functions which I don't like. Therefore I would like to know if there is a straight-forward way to get this by hand.

Comment: I'm not familiar with these techniques myself, but I remember seeing the case m = a = 1 done with both contour integration and gamma/beta functions plus the reflection formula. This can probably be done similarly?

Comment: minor remark: you might want to demand $a > 0$ as well.

Comment: Yes I missed that

Comment: @Listing Another way is putting $x^{m-1} = e^t$ to get an integral solvable by infinite series of $\dfrac{1}{1+e^t}$. It produces ($u = \dfrac{m}{n}$) $$\sum\limits_{k =  - \infty }^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^k}}}{{u + k}} = \frac{\pi }{{\sin \pi u}}} $$ [which I still need to show is true](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110494/possibility-to-simplify#comment258015_110494).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well there is actually a formula which I found in Gamelin's complex analysis book. This is problem number $7$ **Exercise VII.4 Page No. 208**. This works for the case $a=1$. So if you have $a=1$, then $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^{b}} \ \text{dx} = \frac{\pi}{b \sin(\pi{a}/b)}, \quad 0 < a < b$$

> Set $$I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^{b}} \ \text{dx}$$ and integrate $$f(z) = \frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z^{b}} = \frac{|z|^{a-1} \cdot e^{i(a-1)\text{arg}(z)}}{1+|z|^{b}e^{ib\text{arg}(z)}}$$
>
> Simple pole at $z_{1} = e^{\pi{i}/b}$ and hence $$\text{Res} \Biggl[\frac{z^{a-1}}{1+z^{b}}, e^{\pi{i}/b}\Biggr] = \frac{z^{a-1}}{bz^{b-1}}\Biggl|_{z =e^{\pi i / b}} = -\frac{1}{b}e^{\pi i a/b}$$
>
> Integrate along $\gamma_{1}$, and let $R \to \infty$ and let $ \epsilon \to 0^{+}$. This gives, 
>   \begin{align*}
>  \int\limits_{\gamma_{1}} f(z) \ dz & = \int\limits_{\gamma_{1}}  \frac{|z|^{a-1} \cdot e^{i(a-1)\text{arg}(z)}}{1+|z|^{b}e^{ib\text{arg}(z)}} \ dz \\\ &= \int\limits_{\epsilon}^{R} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^{b}} \to \int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-1}}{1+x^{b}} \ dx =I
> \end{align*}
>
> Integrate along $\gamma_{2}$, and let $R \to \infty$. This gives $0 < a < b$ and $$\Biggl|\int\limits_{\gamma_{2}} f(z) dz \Biggr| \leq \frac{R^{a-1}}{R^{b}-1} \cdot \frac{2\pi R}{b} \sim \frac{2 \pi}{b R^{b-a}} \to 0$$
>
> Integrate along $\gamma_{3}$ and let $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$. This gives 
>   \begin{align*}
> \int\limits_{\gamma_{3}} f(z) \ dz &= \int\limits_{\gamma_{3}}  \frac{|z|^{a-1} \cdot e^{i(a-1)\text{arg}(z)}}{1+|z|^{b}e^{ib\text{arg}(z)}} = \Biggl[\begin{array}{c} z=x e^{2\pi i/b} \\\ dz=e^{2\pi i/b} \ dx \end{array}\Biggr] \\\ &= \int\limits_{R}^{\epsilon} \frac{x^{a-1}e^{2\pi i(a-1)/b}}{1+x^{b}} \cdot e^{2\pi i b} \ dx \to \int\limits_{\infty}^{0} \frac{x^{a-1}e^{2\pi i(a-1)/b}}{1+x^{b}} \cdot e^{2\pi i b} \ dx \\\ &= -e^{2\pi ia/b}I
> \end{align*}
>
> Integrate along $\gamma_{4}$ and let $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$. This gives $0 < a <b$, $$\Biggl|\int\limits_{\gamma_{4}} f(z) \ dz \Biggr| \leq \frac{\epsilon^{a-1}}{1-\epsilon^{b}} \cdot \frac{2\pi\epsilon}{b} \sim \frac{2\pi\epsilon}{b} \to 0$$
>
> Using the $\text{Residue Theorem}$ and letting $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^{+}$, we obtain that $$ I + 0 - e^{2\pi a/b}I + 0 = 2\pi i \cdot \Bigl(-\frac{1}{b} e^{\pi ia/b}\Bigr)$$ This yields, $$(e^{-\pi i a/b} - e^{\pi i a./b})I= -\frac{2\pi i}{b}$$ and hence solving for $I$, we have $$I= \frac{2\pi i}{b \cdot (e^{\pi ia/b} - e^{-\pi i a/b})}=\frac{\pi}{b \sin(\pi a/b)}$$

Actually I have taken this answer from, one of my posts: You can see that as well.

- [Simpler way to compute a definite integral without resorting to partial fractions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34351/simpler-way-to-compute-a-definite-integral-without-resorting-to-partial-fractions/37372#37372)

Comment: why was this downvoted?

Comment: @Thomas: Perhaps, because, this doesn't exactly answer the question and only answers a small case.

Comment: I feel this answer should remain because: 1) Methods involved in evaluating residue. 2) Some other people might use this and answer the OP's question.

Comment: Yes I too think this is useful. However I am a bit confused with the notation. What is ${arg}(z)$ and ${Res}(z)$? Maybe you should also give the chapter where you found it in case someone wants to look it up.

Comment: Argument of z and residue z respectively, I believe.

Comment: @Listing: Ok, the solution is not there in Gamelin. I shall add the problem number soon :)

Comment: @ Chandru, off-topic, but how good is Gamelin's book? I was thinking of picking up a complex analysis book for the summer, but I'm not sure which one to get! :]

Comment: @Lyrebird: It is a decent bookm infact I like it very much. But if you want see books on complex analysis please see: http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/

Comment: @Listing: Reference added.

Comment: @Chandru -  thank you, I'll look into the list.

Comment: For $a > 0$, let $y = x/a^{1/n}$ and so $x = a^{1/n} y$.
We have:
$$x^n = a y^n$$
$$x^{m-1} = a^{(m - 1)/n} y^{m - 1}$$
$$dx = a^{1/n} dy$$
And for the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac {x^{m - 1}} {a - x^n} dx = a^{m/n - 1}\int_0^\infty \frac {y^{m - 1}} {1 - y^n} dy$$

Comment: Thanks. If $a\neq0$ you can maybe just do some clever substitution to reduce it to this case. Edit: Too late AlbertH got it before :-)

Comment: @Chandru Isn't it missing how the $\gamma_1$ to $\gamma_4$ are actually defined?

Comment: @Listing: Yes, the graph is missing,

Comment: Ok I accepted it because after thinking about the problem it is obvious how the graph looks :-) Thank you for the detailed answer.