# Is there a solution to the definite integral, $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$ where, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating this integral for different values of a constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180998/evaluating-this-integral-for-different-values-of-a-constant)

Is there a solution to the definite integral, $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^{\frac{1}{n}}}\frac{1}{1+x^2}\mathrm{d}x$$ where, $n \in \mathbb{N}$

HINT : substitute, $x = \tan\theta$

Comment: Are you giving us a hint ?

Comment: I wonder if there's something special about $n\in\Bbb N$ and $x=\tan\theta$ that makes this question seek a different type of answer than the one given in the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Maple says that $$\int\limits_0^{\infty}x^{-1/n}\dfrac 1{x^2+1}dx=\dfrac 12\pi\sec\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2n}\right)$$