# Generalization of certain type of rational integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am thinking on integrals of the form

$$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1)(x^2+1) } dx $$

First of all, we have to realize that integral only make sense if $a>2$.

If $a=0$, we can just apply partial fractions, so it is easy.

If $a=1$, then pretty much as before and same with $a=2$.

My question is, how about if $a=1/2$ or $a=3/2$, does the integral have closed form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note $\frac{ 1}{(x+1)(x^2+1) } = \frac12\left(\frac{1}{x+1 }+\frac{1-x}{x^2+1 }\right)$ and

$$ \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1)(x^2+1) } dx 
=\frac12 \int\limits_0^{\infty}\left( \dfrac{ x^a }{x+1 } + \frac{ x^{a}}{x^2+1 } -\frac{ x^{a +1}}{x^2+1 } 
\right)dx\\
=\frac\pi4\left(-2\csc\pi\alpha + \sec\frac{\pi\alpha}2+ \csc\frac{\pi\alpha}2\right)
$$

where the result $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{b-1}}{x^m +1}= \frac\pi m \csc\frac{\pi b}m$ is used.

Comment: Great, but how you solve the result in your last line, do you have any link?

Comment: @Theoneandonly see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/110457/closed-form-for-int-0-infty-fracxn1-xmdx

Comment: However, your work only works when $a<-1$

Answer (score 2):

Using partial fractions,
$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1)(x^2+1) } dx = \frac 1 2 \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1) } dx + \frac 1 2 \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x^2+1) }  - \frac 1 2 \int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^{a+1} }{(x^2+1) }dx$$
Now using [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44928/interesting-integral-formula)
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\alpha-1}}{1+x^{\beta}} \ \text{dx} = \frac{\pi}{\beta \sin\left(\pi\frac{\alpha}\beta\right)}, \quad 0 < \alpha < \beta$$
Thus
$$\boxed{\int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1)(x^2+1) } dx = \frac 1 2 \left(\frac {\pi}{\sin(\pi(a+1))} +\frac {\pi}{2\sin\left(\pi\frac{a+1}2\right)} - \frac {\pi}{2\sin\left(\pi\frac{a+2}2\right)}\right)}$$

Answer (score 2):

I shall not repeat the steps already given in answers but give the most compact form I was able to find
$$\int\limits_0^{\infty} \dfrac{ x^a }{(x+1)(x^2+1) } dx=\frac{\pi }{2 \left[1+\sqrt{2} \sin \left((2 a+1)\frac{\pi}{4} \right)\right]}$$

Comment: Where did you find it? Any reference?

Comment: @Theoneandonly. Same steps as in other answers but trigonometric simplifications.